# A question on transforming a non-inverting comparator to an inverting one?

Tags: comparator, inverting-amplifier, non-inverting

Here is the schematics for the question:

[image]

I was using the LM311 as a non-inverting comparator without problem.

It works fine and here is the output below:

[image]

But if I use it as an inverting comparator, I get the following output below. As you see the output pulses have distorted tips. I circled one of them with orange color.

[image]

Is my transformation of the non-inverting comparator to an inverting comparator just by swapping inputs correct? How can I fix those non-flat corners?

Comment: Your circuit has a feedback loop. What is this for? Can you remove the feedback R5 and R10?

Comment: oh yes i removed them both works fine now. besides that, do you think swapping inputs is enough?

Comment: Note that the feedback (through R5 and R10) should be a positive feedback which gives you hysteresis. It means that the "flip high" and "flip low" voltages get separated. R5 is placed correctly to the + input giving pos. feedback. R10 is NOT placed correctly, it gives negative feedback here and that reduces the gain which is undesired if you want to make a comparator !

Comment: do you mean R5 should be there but R10 should be removed? is that right what i understand?

Comment: R10 should not feed-back to the - input but to the + input. You might then also need to make C2 smaller or even remove it as that reference voltage will go up and down slightly when the output switches.

Comment: but when I wire R10 to + input, this time the output pulse tops are not sharp as when I remove R10. ?

Comment: On the contrary, the positive feedback will help to make sharp edges at the output. It's like giving the opamp an extra kick in the right direction when it wants to switch.

Comment: maybe what i see is the performance of LM311. i noticed both configurations have that issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that this has something to do with the feedback loop (connected through R5 and R10).

Your non-inverting comparator looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWdCdC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and your inverting comparator looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzJgNL.png)</sup>

In the non-inverting comparator, you have positive feedback: when input > bias, the output swings high, which makes the input even higher! That way, the output voltage stays where it is.

However, in the inverting comparator, you have a negative feedback loop: when the output goes high, it drags the input voltage a little bit lower, which makes the comparator turn back off. This is the "ringing" that you see.

All you need to do (as I mentioned in the comments) is take out this feedback - a comparator doesn't need it. This should remove your overshoot.

Comment: just to be sure in both inverting and noniverting there shouldnt be any feedback rght?

Comment: Correct. If you go hunting for LM311 circuits online, you'll notice that none of them have feedback.

Comment: In a comparator you can have feedback but that should be POSITIVE feedback which results in hysteresis. But then you've made a schmitt-trigger instead of a pure comparator ! So negative feedback: no; positive feedback: only if you want it.

Comment: hmm so is that fine both have positive feedback?

Comment: schmitt-trigger  is better for my application since i want to sharpen pulses

Comment: No not both, in the positive feedback case the feedback signal goes back to the positive input of the opamp. So have a look which one has positive feedback and which one does not.

Comment: Note that in a schitt-trigger the "flip output up" and the "flip output down" voltages are not identical ! This prevent the output from flipping up and down when the input voltage is around the tripping voltage.

Comment: so if i have an inverting comparator. since i cannot make positive feedback, i cant make a schmitt trigger?

Comment: Sure you can, connect R10 to + input and remove C2, now you will have an inverting schmitt-trigger

Comment: how is this now: http://postimg.org/image/nlva61y3r/ ??

Comment: capacitor also should be removed in non-inverting schmitt trigegr case?? I mean C1